# Why doesn't CIOEngine have a dispatcher in kotlin script?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor, kotlin-script

I have the following code in a file testKtor.main.kts:

```
@file:DependsOn("com.aallam.openai:openai-client-jvm:3.7.0")
@file:DependsOn("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio-jvm:2.3.9")

import com.aallam.openai.client.OpenAI

val openAiClient = OpenAI(token = "your-api-token")
```

When running this with `kotlin testKtor.main.kts` I get this exception:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.ktor.client.engine.cio.CIOEngine does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher getDispatcher()' of interface io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine.
> at io.ktor.client.engine.cio.CIOEngine.(CIOEngine.kt:29)
> at io.ktor.client.engine.cio.CIO.create(CIOCommon.kt:35)
> at io.ktor.client.HttpClientKt.HttpClient(HttpClient.kt:42)
> at io.ktor.client.HttpClientJvmKt.HttpClient(HttpClientJvm.kt:21)
> at com.aallam.openai.client.internal.HttpClientKt.createHttpClient(HttpClient.kt:89)
> at com.aallam.openai.client.OpenAIKt.OpenAI(OpenAI.kt:60)
> at com.aallam.openai.client.OpenAIKt.OpenAI(OpenAI.kt:40)
> at com.aallam.openai.client.OpenAIKt.OpenAI$default(OpenAI.kt:30)
> at TestKtor_main.(TestKtor.main.kts:6)

I checked, the `CIOEngine` in `ktor-client-cio-jvm` depends on `ktor-client-core-jvm` where the dispatcher is implemented in the `HttpClientEngineBase`. It should exist.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to reorder the dependencies. This works:

```
@file:DependsOn("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio-jvm:2.3.9")
@file:DependsOn("com.aallam.openai:openai-client-jvm:3.7.0")

import com.aallam.openai.client.OpenAI

val openAiClient = OpenAI(token = "your-api-token")
```

As to why, I can give an educated guess:

The `openai-client-jvm` library depends on the multiplatform version of `ktor-client-core` via the multiplatform `commonMain` sourceset (see [build.gradle.kts](https://github.com/aallam/openai-kotlin/blob/main/openai-client/build.gradle.kts)). I assume the kotlin script cannot handle this multiplatform dependency correctly. However through the `ktor-client-cio-jvm` dependency we somehow get the correct version of `ktor-client-core` (maybe because its a `project` dependency, see [built.gradle.kts](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/main/ktor-client/ktor-client-cio/build.gradle.kts)).

Now depending on the order of our operations, the openai library can either find the ktor core correctly or it gets the `non-jvm` version and it fails.